# How to create if loops using values from two different sets <select> elements

Tags: javascript, html, loops, if-statement, select

there. I'm super new to coding, and I'm trying to understand how to organize my code. I have two select elements in my html, that i would like to call separately, but i don't know how to appropriately go about it. I would like to call the two different events so that when each one is selected individually, it pulls data from its individual set of option values.

From there, I will use the results to build loops that will then give concatenated results in a third string.

```
var select = document.getElementById('weather');
var para = document.getElementById('alf');

select.addEventListener('change', setWeather);

function setWeather() {
var choice = select.value;

if (choice === 'sunny') {
  para.textContent = 'Suns out, guns out.';
} else if (choice === 'rainy'){
  para.textContent = 'Moons out, boons out';
} else if (choice === 'snowy') {
  para.textContent = 'Look, a whale!';
} else {
  para.textContent = '';
}
}
```

So i realize that the above code works for the first instance of select="weather", but i'm not sure how to go about calling the second instance, so that it also receives a call.

```
<label for="weather">Select weather</label>
<select id="weather">
   <option value="">--make a choice--</option>
   <option value="sunny">Sunny</option>
   <option value="rainy">Rainy</option>
   <option value="snowy">Snowy<option>
</select>

<p id="alf"></p>

<label for="">Select weather</label>
<select id="dance">
   <option value="">--make a choice--</option>
   <option value="hail">Sunny</option>
   <option value="rail">Rainy</option>
   <option value="cat">Snowy<option>
</select>
```

ideally, I'd like be able to call information from 'select id="weather" and select id="dance", separately, and at the same time. Any news would be good news. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), I would suggest to loop through elements in `document.querySelectorAll('select')` and assign the event listener to each element. In `setWeather` you could differentiate between the elements by introducing a parameter to `setWeather(event)`. Also, you might want to look into jQuery which makes things a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setWeather() {
  var choice = this.value;  // use this
  //...
  //Suggest : if  ->  switch...case
}

document.getElementById('weather').addEventListener('change', setWeather);
document.getElementById('dance').addEventListener('change', setWeather);
```

Comment: This worked! thank you! Now i just have to figure out how to run a function that grabs the result of those two switch loops, but I think I can make that happen. This was my biggest hurdle!

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that you want to get the value of both select simultaneously?
maybe this can help..

```
var weather = document.getElementById('weather');
weather.addEventListener('change', setWeather); 

var dance = document.getElementById('dance');
dance.addEventListener('change', setWeather);

var para = document.getElementById('alf');

function setWeather() {
  weatherVal = weather.value;
  danceVal = dance.value;

  para.textContent =  weatherVal +'-'+danceVal;
}
```